# Openswan and sonicwall and encryption parameters

Tags: vpn, openswan

This error leads me to investigate my encryption parameters:

```
003 "sonicwall" #2: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [...]
```

Can some expert please have a look at tell me what is wrong?

Sonic wall (web interface):

```
ESP: 3DES/HMAC SHA1 (IKE)
IKE phase 1: Enc 3DES, auth SHA1
Ipsec Phase 2: Protocol ESP, Enc 3DES, Auth SHA1
Required XAUTH
DH Group 2
```

/etc/ipsec.conf

```
ike=3DES-SHA1;modp1024
phase2alg=3DES-SHA1;modp1024
```

This gets me through phase 1 (key exchange) but then it gets stuck at phase 2 (data exchange) where it is looping and reporting malformed payload notifies:

```
002 "sonicwall" #2: initiating Main Mode
104 "sonicwall" #2: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
003 "sonicwall" #2: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [...]
002 "sonicwall" #2: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
106 "sonicwall" #2: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
003 "sonicwall" #2: ignoring Vendor ID payload [Sonicwall 1 (TZ 170 Standard?)]
003 "sonicwall" #2: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
003 "sonicwall" #2: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
002 "sonicwall" #2: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
108 "sonicwall" #2: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
002 "sonicwall" #2: received 1 malformed payload notifies
003 "sonicwall" #2: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3
010 "sonicwall" #2: STATE_MAIN_I3: retransmission; will wait 20s for response
002 "sonicwall" #2: received 2 malformed payload notifies
003 "sonicwall" #2: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3
010 "sonicwall" #2: STATE_MAIN_I3: retransmission; will wait 40s for response
002 "sonicwall" #2: received 3 malformed payload notifies
```